# Compare two large tables mssql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I courrently have two tables (more then 2 million records) and i have to compare them to get same records and the same numbers.
The structures like A and B tables too:

```
crate table A(
name nvarchar(255)
number nvarchar(20)
)
```

I have some issues in the solution:
-I have some records what contains some '?' where need to be language special characters.
-Have some records in the name cloumn all the two tables what like:

```
insert into A('.','1')
insert into A('.','1')
insert into A('.','2')
insert into A('.','3')
insert into A('.','1')
```

an the B table have same problem.
Cause the tables are large i can't use the join methods with distincts soo i have a lot of duplication(result are more then 50million records) and I can't use union all because the results are same duplication problem.
What need to do to the result be a valid number what the A and B are contains too?

Comment: Do your tables have primary keys?

Comment: the name column like uniqe but have special cases like in the example. In the majority rows are name is expessialy uniqe

Comment: you simply don't have many choices. Create indexes on columns, or if values are similiar, select with group by in temp table and then index the temp table. Or you can use some comparing tool for sql server. But, table without a primary key and indexes, is not a table anymore, it's heap

Comment: If your table has PK or unique column, then use tablediff.exe tool, it's part of SQL Server tools.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't unique column, maybe in the data pairs name-number have different combinations. I tried UNION and EXCEPT methods but don't know the the result are valid because i can't test it just with JOIN methods but If I use those I get out of memories exceptions or my query lunch after 5hour without result.